# Smartrmail Creating a newsletter signup with multiple options

Tags: php, html, forms, newsletter

We use smartrmail for our newsletter service for my work, and currently they have no way to create a signup form where a customer can choose which mailing lists they would like to be added to.
For example, we want allow customers to be able to choose what emails they recieve i.e Radio control, model kits or model railway emails.

I want the form to look like the following,
Email Address text box

"Select which mailing lists you wish to be added to" Label

Checkbox 1 : Radio control cars.
Checkbox 2 : Model Kits.
Checkbox 3 : model railway.
Submit Button.

Now I am just wondering how to go about this as the current code caters for signing up to one default mailing list, and the form action calls a signup form page created by smartrmail (Which i can create for the 3 mailing list radio control, model kits and model railway.

The current code for our signup for is as follows:

```
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://go.smartrmail.com/en/subscribe/7iypic" method="post" id="subscribe-form">
                      <input name="subscribe_form[anti_bot]" type="text" style="display: none" />
                      <label for="subscriber_email">Email</label>
                      <input class="form-control" id="subscriber_email" name="EMAIL" type="email" required placeholder="Email Address" />
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="y" class="terms_box" required/>
                            I have read and agree to
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termsModal">Terms & Conditions</a> and
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#privacyModal">Privacy Policy</a>.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <input name="commit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Subscribe" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin' style='font-size: 14px'></i>"/>
                </form>`enter code here`
```

Comment: So you have to switch to a different form action, based on which list the user chooses, is that what you are saying? Then you should set that dynamically with JavaScript, based on the user’s choice.

Comment: Yea that's what it needs to do, I am very much a beginner when it comes to this.
So obviously I can find out which boxes are checked with getElementById().checked
and I could use 3 if statements for each list to add to the list or not add to the various lists.
So how exactly do I replicate what the form does with submitting the data to this page
 action="https://go.smartrmail.com/en/subscribe/7iypic" 

I can get the email address from the form using again getElementById but how exactly do I pass that through to the URL like the form would do?

Comment: You don’t need to pass anything yourself, if you just set the form action to the appropriate target URL, and then _submit_ the form.